# Add multiple Widgets Sidebar for specific template?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wordpress and I just want to know: How can I add multiple widgets sidebar into a template?

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-bookpost' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-bookpost' ); ?>
```

Will this work for different types of widgets?

Comment: In the widgets section, you can drag multiple widgets to the widget area.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put different sidebar widgets on different pages, or just stack multiple widgets in the same sidebar?
If you are just trying to stack multiple widgets, you can do just as Howlin said and drag as many as you need into the Bookpost Sidebar.

If you want to have different sidebars on different pages, you can either use a plugin like widget logic that allows you to only show certain widgets on certain pages, or get a little deeper into php and functions, and create your own custom widget areas.